# How to check that maximum user can join a contest - concurrent request

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I need to check a user that he can join in a particular contest or not.
Suppose I set that 100 users can join the contest. To check that First, I am querying to the contest table to get the maximum number if the condition satisfies then updating the table by incrementing the join contestant by 1.

My problem is that - when concurrent users are trying to join the contest it’s getting incremented even the 100 crosses as because some user already entered to the iteration with the early counter which is not updated by then.

Please suggest some solution

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. What RDBMS are you *really* using? I've removed the conflicting tags (and added SQL for now), please retag the correct one. Posting your code will also greatly help, as we can't debug code or change the way it functions without said code. Thanks.

Comment: @DanGuzman: use `<`, not `<=`.

Comment: In Microsoft SQL Server, you could do something like: UPDATE dbo.Contest SET UserCount +=1 WHERE ContestID = 1 AND UserCount < 100; IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 PRINT 'only 100 users allowed';

Comment: In mysql you can create a [named lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html) and then don't let people connect if the lock has been created. When the join completes release the lock. Those who are trying to join should keep trying to get a lock until the contest is full.

Comment: php, asp.net, and node.js in the same question! That's three different backend stacks. Which one is it? (Please don't overuse tags.)

Comment: Guys what if do it using session and counter. @DanGuzman

Comment: @imZiaur, do you mean user session? Each would have a separate counter in that case. This concurrency problem can be handled by the DBMS you are using but, unless to tell us which one you are using, we can't provide a concrete answer. Same applies to the technology stack if you want to address the problem at the app layer. Your question to too broad as it stands.